# Sub divs do not show button inline

Tags: css

I have the following movie element:

[image]

And this is the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="bottom d-flex">
    <div class="video-controls time-segment p-2">
        <button class="btn-control btn-"><span class="fa fa-undo"></span></button>

        <button class="btn-control btn-step-backward"><span
                class="fa fa-step-backward"></span></button>

        <button *ngIf="!widget.moviePlaying" class="btn-control btn-play" (click)="playPauseMovie(widget)"><span class="fa fa-play"></span></button>

        <button *ngIf="widget.moviePlaying" class="btn-control btn-pause" (click)="playPauseMovie(widget)"><span class="fa fa-pause"></span></button>

        <button class="btn-control btn-step-forward"><span
                class="fa fa-step-forward"></span></button>

        <button class="btn-control btn-reset" hidden><span class="fa fa-undo"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div id="frames-indicator">
        <span id="seekBarLabel">Frame {{ moviesFrames.current }}/{{ moviesFrames.total }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="widget-controls ml-auto">
        <button class="btn-control btn-play" (click)="setSize(widget, 1, $event, gridster1)"><span
                class="fa fa-clone"></span></button>

        <button *ngIf="!widget.linked" class="btn-control btn-" (click)="toggleLinked(widget)"><span
                class="fa fa-chain-broken"></span></button>

        <button *ngIf="widget.linked" class="btn-control btn-step-backward" (click)="toggleLinked(widget)"><span class="fa fa-link"></span></button>

        <button class="btn-control btn-play" (click)="setSize(widget, -1, $event, gridster1)"><span
                class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>
        <button class="btn-control btn-play" (click)="setSize(widget, 1, $event, gridster1)"><span
                class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see:

1. div container has class="bottom d-flex"
2. div 1 has class class="video-controls time-segment p-2" and host buttons
3. div 2 just contain a span element
4. div 3 is right aligned and host buttons

I want div 1 and 3 to 'expand their width to display all buttons inline. I have tried width: max-content with no luck.

Any idea in how to achieve my goal?

**SOLUTION**

Thank you to everyone for trying to help. In the end I did not need to manipulate the CSS. The media breakpoint settings were wrong. I was generated the same number of movies per line in medium and large screens. On Medium screens the movies were too narrow causing the icons to stack vertically.

Comment: Hey, could you post a linkt to a complete example on a playground, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Please do not post your code as images since it's difficult to reproduce your code

Comment: @haja, the SO Editor has its own snippet widget :) And, and least in my opinion, it is better to keep code here than as a volatile external resource.

Comment: @Philippe sure, you can keep the code here as well, but a playground definitely helps with analysis. and, the actual css code is missing, so please provide this as well.

as a side note: a working playground example is often a good way of diagnosing the problem yourself ;)

Comment: Hi Dino ! The final frontend html code and the css you apply on it would help us to reproduce it *in a snippet* and try to solve your issue :)

Comment: @haja You are **required** to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob but html only is not a reproducible example. I am not arguing against having all code in here. I'm just saying it would help to have a jsfiddle _as well_

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own solution in case might help someone.

Thank you to everyone for trying to help. In the end I did not need to manipulate the CSS. The media breakpoint settings were wrong. I was generated the same number of movies per line in medium and large screens. On Medium screens the movies were too narrow causing the icons to stack vertically.